# Django - Find out which model the variable belongs to

Tags: python, django

If I pass a variable as an argument, Can I find out which model it belongs to?

For example, if there is some_model, can I find out if it belongs to model Pizza or Toppings, etc?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Passing an object to `type()` will tell you the type of the object.

```
print type(some_model)
```

Answer (score 8):

Test if some_model is of type inherited from MyType

```
issubclass(type(some_model), MyType)
```

Test if some_model is instance of MyType

```
isinstance(some_model, MyType)
```

Answer (score 0):

For if statements this worked for me

```
from app.models import SomeModel
model_var = SomeModel()
if type(model_var) == SomeModel:
    #Do stuff
    pass
```